# Подскажите библиотеку для манипуляции png

Tags: c++, поиск-библиотек, png, обработка-изображений

Подскажите, кто знает библиотеку для png (C++), которая будет иметь функционал:
загрузить картинку, нарезать ее на куски и сохранить отдельные элементы с указанием размера изображения и центра?

Comment: Я думаю Pillow подойдёт, но судя по меткам у вас c++, но в вопросе ничего про конкретный язык не сказано. (PS: Pillow для Python).

Comment: библиотеку под с++ желательно

Comment: @чистов_n, там в метках написано C++.  Я понимаю, сам путался)

Comment: @Глеб я вашу правку принял, но нужен ещё один...

Comment: @чистов_n, о, уже все, принята.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024857/easy-to-use-png-lib

Comment: Нужно кроссплатформенно или как? Если только под Винду, то GDI+. Я использовал, всё работало.

Comment: Imagemagick может все!